# get image from video without specifying height

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am using following code for extracting image from Video.

```
shell_exec('echo "Y" | ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i "'.base_path().'/assets/videos/'.$file_name.'.mp4" -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 1170x300 "'.base_path().'/assets/videos/thumbnail/'.$file_name.'.jpg"');
```

Here I have given static height and because of that image is stretching So I don't want to specify height so is there any way it adjust height automatically by maintaining quality of image.

I have tried following code as well but did not work

```
shell_exec('echo "Y" | ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i "'.base_path().'/assets/videos/'.$file_name.'.mp4" -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 1170x-1 "'.base_path().'/assets/videos/thumbnail/'.$file_name.'.jpg"');
```

Can anyone tell me solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, if `echo "Y" |` is intended to overwrite an existing thumbnail without prompting, there is a `-y` flag to `ffmpeg` which does this.

Now, assuming you want the image to be **no larger than** 1,170 pixels in **either** dimension, you can replace your `-s` parameter with a call to the `scale` video filter and appropriate arguments.

```
shell_exec(
    'ffmpeg -y -itsoffset -4  -i "'.base_path().'/assets/videos/'.$file_name.'.mp4"'
    . ' -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo'
    . ' -filter:v "scale=iw*min(min(1170/iw\,1170/ih)\,1):ih*min(min(1170/iw\,1170/ih)\,1)"'
    . ' "'.base_path().'/assets/videos/thumbnail/'.$file_name.'.jpg"');
```

This doesn't scale up videos that are smaller than 1,170 pixels in both directions. If you'd prefer to scale up these thumbnails, replace `scale=iw*min(min(1170/iw\,1170/ih)\,1):ih*min(min(1170/iw\,1170/ih)\,1)` with `scale=iw*min(1170/iw\,1170/ih):ih*min(1170/iw\,1170/ih)`.

If the image should **always** have a width of 1,170 pixels even if this makes it taller than 1,170 pixels high, instead use `scale=1170:ih*1170/iw`.

And finally, to reduce the width to 1,170 pixels only if it's wider, `scale=min(iw\,1170):min(ih\,ih*1170/iw)`

Comment: I am getting black portion on top/bottom of image so can you suggest me what can be the solution?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I don't get that problem with my videos. Perhaps raise a further question and see if anyone has experienced it?

Comment: added new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38047384/poster-adjustment-after-getting-it-from-video, if you can help me in this case.